# Representing Color Using Just An Integer - Javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, kendo-colorpicker

Let' say that I'm using kendo ui [color picker widget](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/colorpicker/mvvm). The widget expects hexadecimal color values. But the colors are represented by just one integer in the database. So I need a function to convert integer color to hexadecimal color and vice versa.

For example, I have the value -16777216 for a color in db. How can this number represent a color and how can I convert it to hexadecimal format?

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please give example of input and expected output and whatever script you have written so far

Comment: from the database..Are you getting values for all three components R,G,B?

Comment: I added an existing color value to question.

Comment: It's possible to encode the three numbers that make up a colour as a single integer, but I'm not aware of any standardised way to do so and we have no idea what method was used when storing the value in your database. This makes it pretty much impossible to tell you how to decode it back into a standard form.

Comment: Your value is highly unlikely since it is a) negative and b) 1000000 in hex

Comment: I provided an answer to convert integer to hex and back ... "**I need a function to convert integer color to hexadecimal color**".  I was told that is not what is being asked ... color is hex value, you want to convert to integer and back.  There was concern that a negative integer produces a negative hex value ... IT SHOULD.  I really don't need to lose reputation because basic math is not understood.

Comment: You know what, I am going to leave it, since it is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert a number to a hexadecimal string with:

```
var hexString = num.toString(16);
```

and reverse the process with:

```
var num = parseInt(hexString, 16);
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL. You have to pass `parseInt` a string that can be converted into a number. `#aabbcc` is not a string, and even if it was then it would represent three different numbers with a # sign to tell you what the format was.

Comment: Re edit: This still doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question (which is about encoding colours, not simple conversion of hex to dec or vice versa).

Comment: alert((-16777216).toString(16)); prompts -1000000. Are you sure about that's ok?

Comment: @anilca A negative value should product a negative hex value.

Comment: @Quentin "**I need a function to convert integer color to hexadecimal color**"

Comment: @rfornal — Emphasis on *color* and the examples of the data format being used in the question. Converting a single number from hex to dec and back doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I just tested this and it seems to do exactly what is being asked for. You might have to parse and add/remove the "#" but otherwise it takes a hex representation of a color converts it to an int and back. I just tried with a color from the color picker and it worked fine:

var number = parseInt('c83030', 16);
console.log(number) // ~> 13119536;
var hexString = number.toString(16);
console.log(hexString) // ~> c83030;

Comment: @dan_paul — The colour, from the question, is -16777216. That converts to -1000000, which isn't anything like a valid CSS colour.

Comment: @Quentin Oh, then it seems impossible to guess what someone elses non-standard encoding scheme is. But if you "need a function to convert integer color to hexadecimal color and vice versa", this answer should work.

Comment: @Quentin, ha, just reread your above comment. I guess we're on the same page.

Comment: @dan_paul — Yes, the question is unanswerable in its current state and should be closed. If you did need that, and the colour used that particular format, then this would work, but that's not the question being asked so this isn't an answer to it.